# Create child class from instantiated base class?

Tags: java, inheritance

I know this sounds weird but is it possible to create a child class that inherits from an already instantiated base class? I know I can use DI but im just wondering.

**Edit**: I know this is more a feature of prototype based languages such as javascript. Either way im wondering if this is even worth considering if something like this is possible.

Lets assume I have the following:

```
public class Parent {
  protected id;

  public Base(int id) {
    this.id = id;
  }
}

public class Child extends Parent {
  public void getID() {
    return id;
  }
}
```

So then in my main I would do something like this:

```
Parent x = new Parent(1900);
// How to make a child of this particular base?
// x child = new Child();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to make a child of this particular base?

You can't. The closest you can come is if `Parent` implements a copy constructor and `Child` uses it in a constructor, which would let you create a `Child` that *copied* that particular parent's state...

...which isn't really all that close. As you say, what you're looking for there is prototypical inheritance, which Java just doesn't have.

Comment: So the best I can do is dependency injection?

Comment: @Asperger: Well, I'm not immediately seeing how DI helps you create a child of a particular instantiated base. If `Child` is a *wrapper* on `Parent` I can see how DI would help, but... (Disclosure: It's *extremely* likely you know more about DI than I do. Nearing certainty. :-) )

Comment: Actually all I was thinking about was like a system where I pass in the parent in the new child. So everytime a new child is created it has access to the object I passed in. Oh boy that would be ugly...loads of getters for the fields unless I make them public.